# Is there a more efficient way to parse a fixed txt file in Access than using queries?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a few large fixed with text files that have multiple specification formats in them. I need to parse out the txt files based on a character with a set location in the file.  That character can have a different position in the file.

I have written queries for each of the different specifications (95 of them) with the start position and length hard coded into the query using the mid() function with a WHERE() function to filter the [Record Identifier] from the specification.  As you can see below the 2 specifications in the WHERE() function have different placements in the txt file.

```
\\\
SELECT Mid([AllData],1,5) AS PlanNumber, Mid([AllData],6,4) AS Spaces1, Mid([AllData],10,3) AS Filler1, Mid([AllData],13,11) AS SSN, Mid([AllData],24,1) AS AccountIdentifier, Mid([AllData],25,5) AS Filler2, Mid([AllData],30,2) AS RecordIdentifier, Mid([AllData],32,1) AS FieldType, Mid([AllData],33,4) AS Filler3, Mid([AllData],37,8) AS HireDate, Mid([AllData],45,8) AS ParticipationDate, Mid([AllData],53,8) AS VestinDate, Mid([AllData],61,8) AS DateOfBirth, Mid([AllData],77,1) AS Spaces2, Mid([AllData],78,1) AS Reserved1, Mid([AllData],79,1) AS Reserved2, Mid([AllData],80,1) AS Spaces3
FROM TBL_Company1
WHERE (((Mid([AllData],30,2))="02") AND ((Mid([AllData],32,1))="D"));
\\\
Or 

\\\
SELECT Mid([AllData],1,5) AS PlanNumber, Mid([AllData],6,4) AS Spaces1, Mid([AllData],10,3) AS Filler1, Mid([AllData],13,11) AS SSN, Mid([AllData],24,1) AS AccountIdentifier, Mid([AllData],25,7) AS RecordIdentifier, Mid([AllData],32,22) AS StreetAddressForBank, Mid([AllData],54,20) AS CityForBank, Mid([AllData],74,2) AS StateForBank, Mid([AllData],76,5) AS ZipCodeForBank
FROM TBL_Company1
WHERE (((Mid([AllData],25,7))="49EFTAD"));
\\\
```

Is there a way to Parse out this without having to hard code every position and length into the code?

I was thinking of having a table with all of the specifications in it and have an import function look to the specification table and parse out the data accordingly to a new table or maybe something else.

What I have done is not very scalable and if the format changes a little I would have to go back to each query to change it.

Any Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Of course, you could store this spec in a table, then build up the query in VBA. But that's barely more efficient. Ideally, you'd have a way to infer or look up the formats without programming them all manually.

Comment: Please show sample text file to illustrate your issue. Very curious to see if this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). You might be talking about XML, JSON, YAML, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your situation, I'd want to be able to generate the SQL statement dynamically, as you suggest.

I'd have a table something like:

```
Format#,Position,OutColName,FromPos,Length,WhereValue
1,1,"PlanNumber",1,5,
1,2,"Spaces1",6,4,
...
1,n,,30,2,"02"
1,n+1,,32,1"D"
```

and then some VBA to process it and build and execute the SQL string(s).  The SELECT clause entries would be recognized by having a value in the OutColName field and WHERE clause entries by values in the the WhereValue column.

Of course this is only more "efficient" in the sense that it's a bit easier to code up new formats or fix/modify existing ones.

Comment: You are correct that is what I am looking to do.  I just don’t know how to do it dynamically.  
How can I have sql reference the [Specs] Table to filter the imported [AllData]Txt table with the output column names coming from the [Specs] table from (OutColName) dynamically?